# One pixel 'grab' area when resizing windows

Tags: window

I find it far to hard to grab the top edge of windows to resize them. It seems like there is only a 1 pixel range where the mouse cursor changes to the resize icon. Does anyone know if this range can be increased?

The grab area in the bottom right corner for instance seems to be a lot bigger, like 20pixels.

Comment: It depends on your theme you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab at the corners.  It's substantially larger there.

Answer (score 4):

In many window managers, holding the Alt key will make the whole window a big move/resize zone for the left and right mouse buttons, respectively. If not enabled by default, it is usually a setting you can edit.

Comment: In 18.04 (or I think 17.10+) with Gnome desktop, the default key is Super/Windows

Answer (score 2):

This is answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124414/how-to-customize-window-borders-and-controls) - use the Gnome Tweak tool aka Advanced Window.

Before discovering this I tried 17 themes and none addressed this problem except that in SOME windows I got a slightly bigger area in the bottom right corner which I did NOT have in the shipped themes. All of which is truly rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

Try the top-left and the top-right corners, more grabblable than the bottom ones (which are almost impossible to get...)

Answer (score 0):

Try `alt + RMB`, love that feature.