# How to customize window borders and controls?

Tags: 12.04, themes, metacity

I want to use themes from [Gnome Art](http://art.gnome.org/themes/), but I can't find where to configure `Control/Window Border/Icons` in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I'm not clear with your question.  Do you want to customize a metacity Theme then use it or are you simply asking where to configure for use in Ubuntu 12.04?  The answers are quite different and maybe you should edit your question to reflect this.  If its the latter (which I suspect it is) the Gnome tweak Tool (known as Advanced Settings) is a good place to start.  Type ADV in Dash for Advanced Settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install gnome-tweak-tool

   `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

   2. Download the theme from [Gnome-art](http://art.gnome.org/themes/)(make sure that it is gtk3 theme)
   3. Extract the theme and copy it to the .themes(.icons for icon themes) folder in your home folder (It is hidden by default press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to see it
   4. open advanced settings from unity dash
   5. Move to 'Theme' option on the left sidebar. You can now change the Window theme,icon theme and gtk theme from there  by changing the options in the dropdown list

[image]

Comment: To change the shell theme you will likely need [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).

Comment: So how to use this to customize window borders?

Comment: Note this answer is about Unity, not GNOME 3, which newer versions of Ubuntu use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tools such as:

- Ubuntu tweak
- MyUnity

Comment: Note that Ubuntu does not use Unity any more. Newer versions of Ubuntu use GNOME 3.

Answer (score 2):

In Gnome2 you could further customise a theme by selecting either Controls, Colors, Window Border, Icons. Under Colors-> "Selected Items", you could change the color for "selected items". This changed the Window's border color (of the active theme).

There didn't seem to be a way to do this using gnome-tweak-tool...

UPDATE: But now there does! The response to [How do I change the colors of the Ambiance & Radiance themes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85786/how-do-i-change-the-colors-of-the-ambiance-radiance-themes) explains how to use **gsettings** to override a theme's color setting(s).

This is what I did to change the Window border color and the Window background color:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-color-scheme selected_bg_color:#5598D7;selected_fg_color:#EDE9E3"
```

You can find the default settings for a theme in /gtk-3.0/gtk.css amd /gtk-3.0/settings.ini. Just look for the line that starts with **gtk-color-scheme =**.

Comment: Note this answer is about GNOME 2. Newer versions of Ubuntu use GNOME 3.