# Cannot change window border theme in MATE

Tags: themes, mate

I'm trying to change the window border theme from appearance settings but it's not working. If I use Marco instead of Compiz it works so is this a Compiz problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124414/how-to-customize-window-borders-and-controls

Try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using gconf editor. Go to /apps/metacity/general and change the Theme value to whatever theme you want.