# Where to send feature request?

Tags: window-manager, bug-reporting, resize

My problem is that resizing windows is a pain. (related question: [One pixel 'grab' area when resizing windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105241/one-pixel-grab-area-when-resizing-windows) , but resizing at the edges is still too clumsy, I do know about the drag-to-edge-resizing but that is not appropriate for all scenarios)

I used to set up tiling window managers or do other tweaking, but that is a lot of grief (takes time; not everything will work appropritely, e.g. indicators; you never know what will break with an upgrade; non-official; etc.)

Instead I would like to make a simple request of making the area at which to click for resizing to be much-much-bigger.

My suggestion is that since there are no button on the right side of the window-header, it could be much larger there. For example a sqaure with side-length equal to that of the thickness of the window-header.

Where can I post this rewust so it has the most potential of being realized?

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way of resizing and moving is to press the left Alt key and then click *anywhere* in the window with the first button (move) or the second button (resize). I even completely remove the window decorations to have less clutter on my screen.

If it does not work for you, install ccsm (compiz config settings manager) and enable the plugins "resize window" and "move window". Also, resizing does not work in some laptops where wheel emulation is switched on, for example on [Thinkpads](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint) wwith a Trackpoint you need to turn it off with the command

```
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but just a tip: if you are using Unity, there is one plugin that comes disabled by default called "Unity Grab Handles" that is really handy in this situation.

You can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31877/how-do-i-use-unity-drag-handles) how it works and how you can activate it.